# JavaScript - Canvas won't Show Image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

This code is just suppose to show the image i import but i can't figure out why it doesn't work. Thank you for the help.

```
var app = new FotoPrint();

function FotoPrint() {

this.init = function() {

    this.im = new Image();

    this.im.onload = function () {

        this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        this.ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        this.ctx.drawImage(this.im,0,0);

    };

    this.im.src = "Images/allison1.jpg";

};

};

app.init();
```

Comment: Im no expert at JS, but from reading through this, you need something linked to this on the HTML side? Possibly, `<div id="canvas">`.

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: The only error that firebug showed was that   'this.ctx.drawImage(this.im,0,0);'   
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.

Comment: put `app.init()` into `onload` event to make sure the html is already rendered by browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue, which is why I tend to name my variable *scope* when I'm getting around this (other people use `that` as mentioned in another answer, or something else, it doesn't matter).

All this does is creates a new variable that isn't used anywhere else. Unlike `this` which is a special keyword to reference the object in the current scope. Try this code with the console logging and you should see the difference. *Outside* the onload function `this` refers to your FotoPrint instance, whereas *inside* the onload function `this` refers to the `img` instance.

```
var app = new FotoPrint();

function FotoPrint() {

    var _scope_ = this;

    _scope_.init = function() {

        console.log('`this` outside onload', this);
        console.log('`_scope_` outside onload', _scope_);

        _scope_.im = new Image();
        _scope_.im.onload = function () {

            console.log('`this` inside onload', this);
            console.log('`_scope_` inside onload', _scope_);

            _scope_.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            _scope_.ctx = _scope_.canvas.getContext("2d");
            _scope_.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, _scope_.canvas.width, _scope_.canvas.height);
            _scope_.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            _scope_.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            _scope_.ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, _scope_.canvas.width, _scope_.canvas.height);
            _scope_.ctx.drawImage(_scope_.im,0,0);

        };

        _scope_.im.src = "Images/allison1.jpg";

    };

};

app.init();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation you made this much clearer to me!! :D

Answer (score 2):

*this* will change inside *onload*. Try to set a variable like:

```
var that = this;
```

before *this.im.onload* definition.

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kv0px2m/

Comment: It didn't work on mine. =/ how do i make sure my image source is correct?

Comment: Any error in your console? How is your code? Did you try the fiddle?

Comment: Oh it worked! I forgot to change this to that...

Can you please explain why i had to change it?

Comment: You need to understand how the "this" keyword works in JavaScript. Please read the following references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/5107058